# Populating an Oracle database, using GCC or TOC, does anybody know this?

Tags: sql-server, oracle

In the past, I've worked with Oracle databases.
In order to populate those, I was using commands, like:

```
Program.Object.Create, Field1="Value1", Field2="Value2", ...
```

The name of that technology was called "GCC" or "TOC" (depending of the used version).

I would like to use that technology (or a similar one) for populating other databases (like SQL-Server), because currently we are using SQL for this, something like:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (Field_1, Field_2, ..., Field_n) VALUES (Value_1, Value_2, ..., Value_n)
```

As you can see, the link between `Field_i` and `Value_i` is not that straightforward.

I have no idea about the name of that technology, I don't even if that technology was something public or written in-house.

In case this technology is something public and if it is usable for other database technologies (like SQL-server), can anybody give me a hint?

Thanks in advance

**Edit:** What do I mean, not straightforward?

Imagine a table with ten columns and I would like to modify some values. In SQL, this leads to SQL update queries like:

```sql
UPDATE Table1 SET Name, ID, Cause, SubCause, Feature, SubFeature, Call, SubCall, Type, SubType VALUES (8, 9, 6, 2, 4, 3, 8, 5, 3, 1);
UPDATE Table1 SET Name, ID, Cause, SubCause, Feature, SubFeature, Call, SubCall, Type, SubType VALUES (2, 6, 8, 1, 3, 8, 5, 3, 1, 5);
UPDATE Table1 SET Name, ID, Cause, SubCause, Feature, SubFeature, Call, SubCall, Type, SubType VALUES (9, 6, 5, 2, 4, 8, 6, 3, 2, 4);
```

In order to know which are the subfeatures in those statements, I need to count in which column the subfeatures are present. That seems to be sixth one. Then I need to look for the sixth values and I see the results (3, 8 and 8 again).

In GCC/TOC technology this is far more straightforward (after scrolling :-) ):

```
Program.Table1.Modify,Name="8", ID="9", Cause="6", SubCause="2", Feature="4", SubFeature="3", Call="8", SubCall="5", Type="3", SubType="1";
Program.Table1.Modify,Name="2", ID="6", Cause="8", SubCause="1", Feature="3", SubFeature="8", Call="5", SubCall="3", Type="1", SubType="5";
Program.Table1.Modify,Name="9", ID="6", Cause="5", SubCause="2", Feature="4", SubFeature="8", Call="6", SubCall="3", Type="2", SubType="4";
```

Comment: Your question is a little unclear, especially to someone who's not familiar with "GCC" / "TOC". Could you provide a resource that explains what those technologies are better? I don't see any functional difference between your Oracle code example and your SQL Server one, only a slight syntactical difference, and therefore I don't understand what you mean by "*the link between Field_i and Value_i is not that straightforward*" for your SQL Server example. It appears pretty straightforward to me.

Comment: @J.D.: I edited my question for better understanding. As you see the higher readability of the TOC/GCC command, I'm looking for this (or similar) technology in SQL-server (the DB I'm currently working with.

Comment: Your `UPDATE` statement is invalid and should look more like what you want.  `update table1 set Name=8, ID=9, Cause=6 ...`

Comment: @MichaelKutz: thanks for the remark, I've corrected the statement.

Comment: @Dominique - SQL is still invalid.  Is your problem with `INSERT` or `UPDATE`? are you writing the code for a script or stored procedure or client (eg Java)?

Comment: @MichaelKutz: my question is about both `INSERT` and `UPDATE`, I like to replace those by `Program.Object1.Create, ...` and `Program.Object1.Modify, ...`, which I know as GCC and/or TOC.

Comment: FWIW, I have not seen anything in this space in the MSSQL world. So, nothing "genrally and widely known", assuming GCC / TOC has such status in the Oracle community.

Comment: @TiborKaraszi: I'm not even sure it's "generally and widely known" in the Oracle community: I have worked with those things in a previous employer, which happened to be working with Oracle. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The native T-SQL language also allows inserting / updating via a `SELECT` statement as opposed to hard-coding values. Then you can utilize aliases for better readability to emulate what you're used to in Oracle. For example:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (Field_1, Field_2, Field_n)
SELECT Value_1 AS Field_1, Value_2 AS Field_2, Value_n AS Field_n;
```

Or my personal preference on formatting to increase readability:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (Field_1, Field_2, Field_n)
SELECT 
    Value_1 AS Field_1, 
    Value_2 AS Field_2, 
    Value_n AS Field_n;
```

As far as updates, the "*not straightforward*" example you provided is not valid syntax so it wouldn't work on SQL Server anyway. The correct syntax in T-SQL is:

```
UPDATE Table1 
SET 
    Name = 9, 
    ID = 6, 
    Cause = 5, 
    SubCause = 2, 
    Feature = 4, 
    SubFeature = 8, 
    Call = 6, 
    SubCall = 3, 
    Type = 2, 
    SubType = 4;
```

This naturally is similar to what you're familiar with in Oracle.

Also, if you only wanted to update a subset of the records, such as the ones with `ID = 6` already, then the following example would be how to accomplish that:

```
UPDATE Table1 
SET 
    Name = 9, 
    Cause = 5, 
    SubCause = 2, 
    Feature = 4, 
    SubFeature = 8, 
    Call = 6, 
    SubCall = 3, 
    Type = 2, 
    SubType = 4
WHERE ID = 6; -- Updates only the records whose ID already = 6
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. And what about the `UPDATE` statement?

Comment: @Dominique Even easier, please see my updated answer.